# jQuery: Unable to trigger function under two conditions

Tags: jquery, function, triggers, resize, conditional-statements

I should start by saying that my jQuery skills are next to none.
I can read most of the stuff, but I have resorted to searching stackoverflow for answers to most of my problems.
Unfortunately I can't figure this one out after a day and a half of trial and error.

I'm modifying a Wordpress theme to have some responsiveness. This theme uses two scripts (columnize.js and columnizer.js) to display posts in three columns.

One of my goals was to make the theme swap between 1, 2 or 3 columns depending on the size of the window.

I'm able to do that on document.ready, but for some reason I can't trigger a change on window.resize under my two conditions (I can just trigger it with a width size change, but it would do it nonstop and a timer isn't what I'm looking for).

I've made these changes to columnize.js, which is being called inside a  right before the .

This is what my latest attempt looks like:

```
    //jQuery.noConflict();
var smallWindow;
var windowsize = jQuery(window).width(); //need to use jQuery instead of $

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if (windowsize < 868) { //if page opens on a small window
        jQuery('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({cols: 2, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1}); //creates the columns
        jQuery('.mcol2').makeacolumnlists({cols: 3, colWidth: 293, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1});
        smallWindow = true; //for the next if condition on resize
        alert(smallWindow); //just to check if it works
    }
    else { //if page opens on a big window
        jQuery('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({cols: 3, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1});
        jQuery('.mcol2').makeacolumnlists({cols: 3, colWidth: 293, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1});
        smallWindow = false;
        alert(smallWindow);
    }
});

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    if ((windowsize < 868) && (smallWindow == false)){
//nothing works here, these conditions were here to keep the function from
//triggering when not necessary, i.e. would only trigger below a certain
//width if window above that width
        jQuery('.mcol').uncolumnlists(); //removes old columns
        jQuery('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({cols: 2, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1}); //creates new columns
        smallWindow = true; //changes to stop the function from triggering on further resize down
        alert(smallWindow);
    }
    else if ((windowsize > 867) && (smallWindow == true)){
        jQuery('.mcol').uncolumnlists();
        jQuery('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({cols: 3, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1});
        smallWindow = false; //changes to stop the function from triggering on further resize up
        alert(smallWindow);
    }
    else !false;
});
```

I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit 1

Thanks for the help. Made a small modification to adeneo's code so it kept the function from triggering non-stop:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var smallWindow = false;
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    if (windowsize < 868 && smallWindow == false) { // did the ! meant false?
        $('.mcol').uncolumnlists();
        $('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({ cols: 2, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1 });
        smallWindow = true;
        //alert(smallWindow);
    } else if (windowsize >= 868 && smallWindow == true) { //now won't trigger unless smallWindow is true
        $('.mcol').uncolumnlists();
        $('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({ cols: 3, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1 });
        smallWindow = false;
        //alert(smallWindow);
    }
}).trigger('resize');
});
```

Only one thing remains, since smallWindow is defined from the start, if the page loads in a window >=868, the function doesn't trigger. Got to scratch my head on that, but I'll share my issue here because you're faster than me. :)

### Edit 2

Okay, I got it. I had to make the smallWindow variable false when it should be true and vice versa, so I could force the resize function to trigger on load.
Still, I feel stupid because I've tried multiple ways but I still can't declare a global variable... So I'm repeating myself with the windowsize var...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var windowsize = $(window).width();
if (windowsize <868) {
    var smallWindow = false;
}
else {
    var smallWindow = true;
};

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    if (windowsize < 868 && !smallWindow) {
        $('.mcol').uncolumnlists();
        $('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({ cols: 2, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1 });
        smallWindow = true;
    } else if (windowsize >= 868 && smallWindow) {
        $('.mcol').uncolumnlists();
        $('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({ cols: 3, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1 });
        smallWindow = false;
    }
}).trigger('resize');
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the resize function inside the `ready` handler, and you need to update the `windowSize` variable on resize as well, otherwise it will always be the same. And no need to type the same stuff twice, just trigger the resize event on pageload:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var smallWindow = false;
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        var windowsize = $(window).width();

        if (windowsize < 868 && !smallWindow) {
            $('.mcol').uncolumnlists();
            $('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({ cols: 2, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1 });
            smallWindow = true;
        } else if (windowsize > 868 && smallWindow) {
            $('.mcol').uncolumnlists();
            $('.mcol').makeacolumnlists({ cols: 3, colWidth: 305, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1 });
            smallWindow = false;
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately it triggers every time it resizes, even when smallWindow is false.

Comment: @MurderOfPoes - seems I removed some of your logic, as it did'nt really see a need for it, but I get it, and added it back!

Comment: Yeah, I made an edit too. Didn't know ! and the lack of meant false and true (looks like it's a bit hard to search exclamation marks on google). Still, now it won't run the function if the page loads on a window >= 868.

Answer (score 0):

smallWindow has to be set to something first (true or false)

Comment: I though I was setting it to either true or false after the document.ready function...